# Parallel processing in R done wrong?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-foreach

I have a code I am trying to process in parallel using the foreach-package. The code is working but when I run it on a computer with 4 cores it takes about 26 min and when I switch to one with 32 cores, it still takes 13 min to finish. I was wondering whether I am doing something wrong since I am using 8 times as much cores, but only reduce the time by one half. My code looks like this:

```
no_cores <- detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)
registerDoParallel(cl)
Xenopus_Data <- foreach(b=1:length(newly_populated_vec),.packages = c("raster", "gdistance", "rgdal","sp")) %dopar% { Xenopus_Walk(altdata=altdata,water=water,habitat_suitability=habitat_suitability,max_range_without_water=max_range_without_water,max_range=max_range,slope=slope,Start_Pt=newly_populated_vec[b]) }
stopCluster(cl)
```

For the computer with 4 cores I get the following time:

```
Time_of_Start
[1] "2016-07-12 13:07:23 CEST"
Time_of_end
[1] "2016-07-12 13:33:10 CEST"

And for the one with 32 cores:
Time_of_Start
[1] "2016-07-12 14:35:48 CEST"
Time_of_end
[1] "2016-07-12 14:48:08 CEST"
```

Is this normal ? and if so, does anyone know how to speed it up additionally, maybe using different packages?
Any type of help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: these are the times I get after applying the corrections as suggested. For 32 cores:

```
User      System     elapsed 
5.99       40.78      243.97
```

For 4 cores:

```
user  system  elapsed 
  1.91    0.94  991.71
```

Note that before, I did the calculation multiple times via some loops, that's why the computation time decreased so drastically, but one can still tell that the difference between the two computers has increased, I believe.

Comment: it's difficult to say if the time is reasonnable without knowing the size of the data compared to the complexity of the calculation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I figured that might be a problem for anybody trying to answer this, but the calculation is based on a rather complex function i wrote myself so I don't think anybody will really work through it if I posted it. Anyway, the data is quite big too, as the function requires several raster layers. Do you have any experience regarding my last question (wheteher there are packages faste rthan foreach and if foreach in general is a good package for parallel processing) ? I am pretty new to the issue...

Comment: First, try to check the number of registered cores by `getDoParWorkers()` to see every thing is fine with that. (before the `foreach`)

Comment: @m0h3n, thanks for the hint. Although the number returned by `getDoParWorkers()` equals the number of cores I have at my disposal this is a useful function I will from now on use to check if everything is fine. didn't know about it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and let me know if your problem is solved:

```
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
registerDoParallel(cores=detectCores())
n <- length(newly_populated_vec)
cat("\nN = ", n, " | Parallel workers count = ", getDoParWorkers(), "\n\n", sep="")

t0 <- proc.time()
Xenopus_Data <- foreach(b=1:n,.packages = c("raster", "gdistance", "rgdal","sp"), .combine=rbind) %dopar% { 
        Xenopus_Walk(
        water=water,
        altdata=altdata,
        habitat_suitability=habitat_suitability,
        max_range_without_water=max_range_without_water,
        max_range=max_range,
        slope=slope,
        Start_Pt=newly_populated_vec[b]) 
}
TIME <- proc.time() - t0
```

Also, try to monitor the logical cores in your PC/laptop to check if all cores are involved in the computation. (TaskManager for Windows and `htop` for Linux)

Please also be mindful that doubling the number of cores does not necessarily lead to having a double performance.

Comment: It worked, thanks. Can you tell me what the difference between our two approaches are so I can understand why yours is working better ? I will edit the new times in my question above.

Comment: @snoops using `registerDoParallel()` takes care of both registering and stopping clusters. Also, `.combine=rbind` is used to combine the result of parallel threads. Moreover, with that timing right before and after the `foreach` loop, you can catch the more accurate time that your parallel work takes.